# How do add where condition only if field is not null

Tags: mysql, sql

currently i am having where clause like `where p.id>5 and p.addedDate > now()` . And i want to have something like `p.id>5 if (NotNullp.aadedDate)  and p.addedDate > now() else` ; is it possible to add `And` operator with condition only if field value is `not null`. so if aadedDate is `null` then query should be like `p.id>5` only no check on `p.addedDate` should applied

Comment: _Column_, not field.

Answer (score 6):

We can use [`IS NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) to check whether the field is `null` or not. `OR` condition will return `TRUE`, if the `addedDate IS NULL`

```
WHERE p.id > 5 AND 
      (p.addedDate IS NULL OR p.addedDate > NOW())
```

Comment: actually i am familiar with this logic . However i was looking for different option .

Comment: @Displayname what do you mean by different option ? This is simplest and *possibly most efficient* way to achieve this

Comment: kind of `p.addedDate IS NOT NULL?p.addedDate > NOW():""`

Comment: @Displayname but why do you want to unnecessarily complicate the condition. I suspect that your problem is broader. Please give more details.